# What questions would be on the Greatest Hits list?

Tags: discussion, faq

It would be great if there was a way to see the questions from Martial Arts that would be on the all time "Greatest Hits" list.

Is there a way to order the questions like this? If the list existed can I see which questions I participated in?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this - but it isn't linked to directly from anywhere on the page.

Here it is: [Martial Arts Greatest Hits](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits)

The legend on the right side of the page gives you some information on how the list is collated - a bunch of statistics is used, including views and feedback on the question.

Note the extra link included in the legend - this will filter the list by the questions that you participated in.

[image]